# Anyway to determine Amazon Machine Image (Creation Date)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I am trying to see if anyone knows how to identify the creation date for Amazon Machine Image(s)?

I have looked all through the documentation on the AWS site, and do not see anything.

The only thing I am thinking is to take the ebs volume snapshot start/end time and use that for my AMI creation date-not sure if that is a "good" method or not.

Comment: I think you have the best idea out there already.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807619/how-to-find-how-amazon-ami-created-date][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807619/how-to-find-how-amazon-ami-created-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line using the ec2 API tools you can do it like this:

```
ec2-describe-snapshots `ec2-describe-images ami-xxxxxxxx | grep snap | awk '{print $4}'` | head -1 | awk '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Going with the 1 liner approach as well.. here's one using the amazon provided aws cli tools:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-ids=`aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids="ami-xxxxxx" | grep snap | awk -F '"' '{print $4}'` | grep StartTime | awk -F'"' '{print $4}'
```

you may need to add -"-region=some-aws-region-1" to specify where you're searching if you don't have it defaulted in your configs.